# How to get user informations by email

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm new in swift programming and I'm working on simple app.  However, I was wondering if I can build "Contact us" view controller where the user enters his message and his data sent to me by email. Is it possible?

example: 
[image]

Comment: try MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: https://github.com/rizumita/CTFeedback

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to send mail from iPhone SDK

1. You could try MFMailComposeViewController to send an email.
2. You could set up a web server from where you could send the email with the help of web services.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll suggest building a web service, post this data as a JSON object, make a fancy email at server end and shot it to concerned email id, you have an option to do any additional task.
Like storing a data to db, tagging it specific way and filtering emails from blacklisted email ids.
You can use mail gun or mail trap to help you setup simple way.